# Finding the OGC API Features endpoint of a FastCGI QGIS server

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-server, ogc-api-features

I have a QGIS Server (3.28) accessible via FastCGI at https://example.com/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?

I can access WFS1/2 fine via e.g. https://example.com/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/path/to/project.qgz&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&ACCEPTVERSIONS=2.0.0,1.1.0,1.0.0

But since [QGIS server also supports the OGC API Features](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/services/ogcapif.html#ogc-api-features) I want to use that.

I assume the server was installed following https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#apache-http-server , at least that seems to result in the same URL structure.

Where can I find the OGC API Features endpoint of this server?

https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/services/ogcapif.html says "The API can be reached on typical installations via `http://localhost/qgisserver/wfs3`". That is sadly not the case.

Comment: I suppose it may depend on what is intended by term `qgisserver` in template url,

Answer (score 0):

In our case the endpoint turned out to be

https://example.com/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi/wfs3/

I am not sure if that is by default.

To specify the project, the URL looks like this:
https://example.com/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi/wfs3/collections?&MAP=/path/to/project.qgz

Comment: Pattern roughly similar to what I have for a MapServer example.  WMS/WFS at `https://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/ows?`  and `https://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/ows/bbsp/ogcapi/collections/` for features API (where `ows` is the equivalent of `qgis_mapserv.fcgi`)